# How to connect multiple MPU-9250 IMU sensors to a single Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c, hardware, imu

The datasheet says the I2C bus limits itself to only two MPU-9250 sensors. How can I control multiple (>2) MPU-9250 through a single Arduino Uno? Is it possible to add another bus?

Please, help.

Comment: this has been asked mamy times ... search this website for `multiple I2C`

Comment: Try this one : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/two-mpu-9250-on-arduino-uno/455724

Comment: I2C is a bus, it's sole purpose is to connect multiple devices together (1 master, multiple slaves)